Failed to get recent blockhash, method not found: Connection.getRecentBlockhash
I am creating a NextJs NFT minting App using the React solana wallet adaptor, web3.js, metaplex and umi.
I was trying to upload the offchain metadata and keep getting the error that the getRecentBlockhash method is not found. I think this has to do with web3.js using the method.
This worked previously before, but today I got this error. I am using the irysUploader.
How can i replace this method with something else that might fix the problem? Thanks!



which uploader service are you using?

I am using the IrysUploader, thanks for the reply!

I am getting the same error. Can you tell how did you fix that? It isn't any web3 library in my package.json so I can't update it

I am getting the same error as well. Can you please share how you fixed this?

getRecentBlockhash has been replaced by getLatestBlockhash (only on devnet for now i think)
since it seems to come from a dependency, may be try to update the dependency in the lastest version ?

Thanks for the help! I will just wair for web3.js v2 i guess. Tried on testnet and it doesnt work as well.

@Flyingsteak did you find a workaround ?
Seems like none of the Metaplex uploaders work.:

Nft Storage library: Webstream error that cannot be fixed.
Bundler & Irys : This Blockhash error
AWS I didn't try, but I don't want to use that for my crypto project :D

Any workarounds ?

You can always fund an Arweave wallet and use arloader - https://github.com/CalebEverett/arloader
Supposedly works --with-sol too
